# excel VBA byref argument passed to function not being changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have been struggling with this for a while and have found some related questions but none seem to solve my problem so it might just be my coding.  The goal is to populate a form from a user defined data type (Customer) and then retrieve the information from the form back into the data object after the user has updated the form.  When I run this code with IOType = "O" it works fine, the data elements are all put into the form.  When I run it with IOType = "I" it reads the text from the form into the DataObjectOrType variable but the customer object that I sent in is not updated (i.e. CurCustomer.name and CurCustomer.territory are both = "").  The underlying data elements of CurCustomer are all strings if that matters.  I have tried this as a sub and a function, with and without parentheses, with and without the byref but nothing seems to make a difference.

update - I have simplified some things and added some code below.  Madgui, you are right that it works with a data type (sub CustomerFormIO2).  It also works with just a couple of strings (sub CustomerFormIO3).  I put the code from the Customer class module below too in case that helps.  I have a feeling this isn't going to work.  Could it have something to do with the Get and Let properties using intermediary variables?  Is there any way to get this to work?

Thanks.

```
Private Type structCustomer
    Name As String
    Territory As String
    Rep As String
End Type

Public Sub CustomerFormIO1()
Dim CurCustomer As Customer
Dim IOType As String
    Set CurCustomer = New Customer
    IOType = "I"
    Call ObjectIO("X", CurCustomer.Name, IOType)
    Call ObjectIO("Y", CurCustomer.Territory, IOType)
    ObjectIO "Z", CurCustomer.Rep, IOType
End Sub

Public Sub CustomerFormIO2()
Dim CurCustomer As structCustomer
Dim IOType As String
    IOType = "I"
    Call ObjectIO("X", CurCustomer.Name, IOType)
    Call ObjectIO("Y", CurCustomer.Territory, IOType)
    ObjectIO "Z", CurCustomer.Rep, IOType
End Sub

Public Sub CustomerFormIO3()
Dim CurCustomerName As String
Dim CurCustomerTerritory As String
Dim CurCustomerRep As String
Dim IOType As String
    IOType = "I"
    Call ObjectIO("X", CurCustomerName, IOType)
    Call ObjectIO("Y", CurCustomerTerritory, IOType)
    ObjectIO "Z", CurCustomerRep, IOType
End Sub

Public Function ObjectIO(FormObject As String, ByRef DataObjectOrValue As Variant, Optional IOType As String) As Variant
    If IOType = "I" Then
        DataObjectOrValue = FormObject
    Else '"O"
        FormObject = DataObjectOrValue
    End If
    ObjectIO = True
End Function
```

Customer Class Module:

```
Private c_CustName As String
Private c_Rep As String
Private c_Territory As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = c_CustName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(CName As String)
    c_CustName = CName
End Property

Public Property Get Rep() As String
    Rep = c_Rep
End Property
Public Property Let Rep(CRep As String)
    c_Rep = CRep
End Property

Public Property Get Territory() As String
    Territory = c_Territory
End Property
Public Property Let Territory(CTerritory As String)
    c_Territory = CTerritory
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
c_CustName = ""
c_Rep = ""
c_Territory = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: In your sub `CustomerFormIO`, you're calling the function `ObjectIO` with the parameters `Customer.Name` and `Customer.Territory` which I assume are string datatype. Strings are a `ByVal` datatypes. Changing `ByRef` to `ByVal` should fix the problem I hope.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to make a difference.  But out of curiosity, I was under the impression that the behavior it is exhibiting is essentially what ByVal would do.  That is, the ObjectIO function is getting the string contents of a variable in DataObjectOrValue but not the variable itself so when I change it the new value is effective in the called function but does not modify the original variable (CurCustomer.Rep, etc.).

Comment: Since you are trying to assign one input parameter to another input parameter, you need both to be `ByRef`, ie. `Function ObjectIO(ByRef FormObject As Object, ByRef DataObjectOrValue  As Variant, Optional IOType As String)`

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work either.  I thought that all objects were passed ByRef by default.  Same thing though.  I can see DataObjectOrValue being populated correctly in the called function but after the code returns to the calling sub the resulting variable (CurCustomer.Rep, etc.) is still blank.

Comment: you should do 2 different functions to call, instead of calling the same, haveing once a list type (combobox) argument, and the next time its a simple string type.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, it works if you define your Customer class as a Type (= static structure ) :

```
Private Type structCustomer
    Name As String
    Territory As String
    Rep As String
End Type
```

In your code change

> Dim CurCustomer As Customer

by

> Dim CurCustomer As structCustomer

and comment the line :

> 'Set CurCustomer = New Customer

Answer (score 0):

(Old post, but adding this since there's no definitive answer here.)

This can be done by passing a reference to the full object `CurCustomer`, but not by passing the property directly. Properties are evaluated and passed as values whether or not `ByRef` is specified.

When passing a `Customer` object, you can add the property directly within the receiving function (`DataObjectOrValue.Name`), but doing so would require extra logic to handle multiple properties in the same function.
You can also pass the property name and use `CallByName` to keep the function flexible.

See the example below.

```
Public Sub CustomerFormIO4()
Dim CurCustomer As Customer
Dim IOType As String
    Set CurCustomer = New Customer
    IOType = "I"
    Call ObjectIO("X", CurCustomer, "Name", IOType)
    Call ObjectIO("Y", CurCustomer, "Territory", IOType)
    ObjectIO "Z", CurCustomer, "Rep", IOType
End Sub

Public Function ObjectIO(FormObject As String, _
        ByRef DataObjectOrValue As Variant, PropName As String, _
        Optional IOType As String) As Variant
    If IOType = "I" Then
        CallByName DataObjectOrValue, PropName, VbLet, FormObject
    Else '"O"
        CallByName DataObjectOrValue, PropName, VbGet, FormObject
    End If
    ObjectIO = True
End Function
```

You can verify that the issue is not unique to user-defined classes by trying the same approach with a worksheet object:

```
Sub wsNameByRefTest()
  Dim ws As Object
  Set ws = Sheets.Add
  ws.Name = "It failed!"
  changeNameByRef ws.Name
End Sub

Sub changeNameByRef(ByRef wsName As String)
  wsName = "It worked!"
End Sub
```

For reference, see this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101(v=vs.84).aspx). It's officially documentation on VBScript, but I've tested in VBA, and all points in the article apply. (ByRef is the default for parameters in both, for example.) I could find no similar reference for VBA specifically.

> ### ByRef Parameters Passed by Value
>
> If the parameter is specified as **ByRef**, the argument can still be passed by value. This occurs if one of the following is true:
>
> - The argument is in parentheses, and the parentheses do not apply to the argument list.
> - The variable sent as an argument is in a class.
> - The argument being passed is not a variable, for example, 12.